# Otro proceso no permite tener acceso a archivo que intento abrir con C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, filesystem

Hice un programa que debe monitorear una carpeta en la cual cada vez que se guarda un archivo XML el programa lo detecta, lo lee (en concreto los values de dos etiquetas nada más) y guarda los datos en una base de datos de SQL Server Express, y he conseguido hacerlo, pero al tercer/segundo archivo XML que se guarda en la carpeta el programa lanza una excepción y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ruta de la carpeta donde estan los archivos xml generados
    private string path = @"C:\Users\HP Omen\Desktop\pruebas C#\monitor_carpeta\monitor_carpeta\recursos";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // monitor de carpeta
        FileSystemWatcher observador = new FileSystemWatcher(path);

        observador.NotifyFilter = (
            NotifyFilters.FileName  | 
            NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
            NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
        );

        // lee solo archivos xml
        observador.Filter = "*.xml";

        // cada vez que haya un evento de creacion ejecutar "leer_y_guardar"
        observador.Created += leer_y_guardar;

        // activar observador
        observador.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    // se lee del archivo xml los datos que interesan y luego se guardan en la base de datos
    private static void leer_y_guardar(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(e.FullPath);

        XmlNodeList node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;

        string fecha_hora = node[1].Attributes["value"].Value;
        string patente    = node[3].Attributes["value"].Value;

        if (fecha_hora.Length == 0 || patente.Length == 0) return;

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-PEOSSRH\\SQLEXPRESS; database=prueba; integrated security=true");
        string sql_insertar = "INSERT INTO registro VALUES ('" + fecha_hora + "','" + patente + "')";
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(sql_insertar, conexion);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
    }
}
```

imagen de la excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso le pasa seguido incluso a un usuario normal. Asegúrate de que ningún programa tenga abierto el archivo. Puedes encontrarlo con process explorer  de systeminternals

Comment: Dale tiempo al programa que genera el archivo a terminar de escribirlo. Cuando te dé IOException, espera un poco y vuelve a intentarlo

Comment: @JesúsLópez  efectivamente.